# can Fans email be extracted from Facebook using the api?

Tags: facebook, api

using the Facebook API it was possible to extract your friends list, is this true of a Fan page you are the administrator of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot pull a list of 'likers' for a given fan page, only the the fan_count which returns the total number of likers. You can see the list of connections for the Page object [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/).